# ANT Scenario Conditional Depend Targets

Tags: ant, jenkins, logic, conditional-statements, dependency-management

Is it possible in ANT to have the same target which depends on set of different targets depending on the condition in this target.

EXAMPLE:

```
<target name=my_target depends="target2,target3,target4" if="my_property1">
```

and

```
<target name=my_target depends="target2,target5,target6" if="my_property2">
```

Where "target2" evaluates properties my_property1 or my_property2.

Is something like this possible, or is there another way to assign to the same target different "depends" based on condition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have duplicate targets.  I'm not quite clear on what you're goign for... what does target2 do with your properties?  To replicate the behavior you have you could setup

`<target name="my_target" depends="target2,target3,target4,target5,target6">`

and then setup `if` and/or `unless` on target1-6 something like

`<target name="target2">` (run target2 always)

`<target name="target3" if="my_property1">`

`<target name="target4" if="my_property1">`

`<target name="target5" if="my_property2">`

`<target name="target6" if="my_property2">`

Comment: I wanted something if my hostname=prd

Comment: hmmm... I understand you don't want to post your real build file, but perhaps if you could flesh out the example more we could help.

Comment: Sorry, i will explain the situation later on the day more clearly